# Referencing a non primary foreign key in Django ORM

Tags: django, django-models, orm, foreign-keys

How can I select entries in one table based on criteria in another table in Django's ORM if the foreign key is not referencing a primary key but another column with unique constraint?
The corresponding SQL command would be:

```
SELECT TableMoon.name
FROM TableMoon JOIN TablePlanet
ON TableMoon.planet = TablePlanet.name
WHERE classification = 'inner_planet';
```

The expected answer would be: Moon, Phobos, Deimos

I tried to rewrite the SQL command from above in Django ORM with either 'planet' or 'planet_id' but I get an empty QuerySet everytime:

```
Tablemoon.objects.filter(planet__classification='inner_planet').values('name')
#Out: <QuerySet []>

Tablemoon.objects.filter(planet_id__classification='inner_planet').values('name')
#Out: <QuerySet []>
```

**Background**
I have a Django app that is connected to a legacy sqlite database. I am not allowed to modify the database scheme. The database looks like this:

```
TablePlanet  
------------------------------------  
planet_id |  name   | classification  
------------------------------------  
1         | Mercury | inner_planet  
2         | Venus   | inner_planet  
3         | Earth   | inner_planet  
4         | Mars    | inner_planet  
5         | Jupiter | outer_planet  
6         | Saturn  | outer_planet  
7         | Uranus  | outer_planet  
8         | Neptune | outer_planet  

TableMoon  
------------------------  
moon_id | planet  | name
------------------------  
1       | Earth   | Moon  
2       | Mars    | Phobos  
3       | Mars    | Deimos  
4       | Jupiter | Io  
5       | Jupiter | Europa  
6       | Jupiter | Ganymede
```

The column `TablePlanet.name` has a unique constraint. The column `TableMoon.planet` has a foreign key constraint that references `TablePlanet.name`.

This is the SQL code for the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE tablePlanet (
  planet_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  name TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  classification TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE tableMoon (
  moon_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  planet TEXT,
  name TEXT,
  FOREIGN KEY (planet) REFERENCES tablePlanet(name)
);
```

My models.py file looks like this

```
from django.db import models


class Tableplanet(models.Model):
    planet_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, null=False)
    name = models.TextField(unique=True)
    classification = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'tablePlanet'


class Tablemoon(models.Model):
    moon_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, null=False)
    planet = models.ForeignKey('Tableplanet', models.DO_NOTHING,
                               db_column='planet', blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'tableMoon'
```

The first thing that puzzles me is Django's naming of the planet-column which is 'planet' in one case and 'planet_id' in the other:

```
Tablemoon._meta.get_fields()
#Out: (<django.db.models.fields.AutoField: moon_id>,
#Out:  <django.db.models.fields.related.ForeignKey: planet>,
#Out:  <django.db.models.fields.TextField: name>)

Tablemoon.objects.all().values()[0]
#Out: {'moon_id': 1, 'planet_id': 'Earth', 'name': 'Moon'}
```

I am grateful for any advice on this!

Comment: Your `planet` is a `ForeignKey` to `planet_id`, not nits name, so the table does not seem to make much sense.

Comment: Unfortunately, `TableMoon.planet` does indeed reference `TablePlanet.name` instead of `TablePlanet.planet_id`. I agree that this very awkward and shouldn't be the case. I wonder whether Django ORM simply refuses to accept such a messy database setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ForeignKey` needs to specify the correct [**`to_field=…`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.to_field), since it does not reference the primary key of the `Tableplanet`:

```
class Tablemoon(models.Model):
    moon_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, null=False)
    planet = models.ForeignKey(
        'Tableplanet',
        models.DO_NOTHING,
        db_column='planet',
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        to_field='name',
    )
    name = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'tableMoon'
```

---

> **Note**: Models normally have no `Table` prefix. A model is not a table, it is stored in a relational database as a table, but even then it has extra logic like validators, managers, etc.

Comment: Adding `to_field='name'` to the model worked. Now I get the correct result with both queries: `Tablemoon.objects.filter(planet__classification='inner_planet').values('name')` and `Tablemoon.objects.filter(planet_id__classification='inner_planet').values('name')`. Thanks a lot! - NB: also agree with your Note.